# Issue Importing Maven (Atlassian JIRA Plugin) Project into Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, maven, plugins, jira, jira-plugin

I am wanting to create a JIRA plugin with the Atlassian JIRA SDK. After creating the project I am encountering several errors when trying to import the project as a Maven project into the Eclipse IDE (Kepler)

Here are the steps that I am taking to produce the error...

1. In PowerShell I create the skeleton with the "**atlas-create-jira-plugin**" command.
2. After creating the plugin skeleton I run "**atlas-mvn eclipse:eclipse**"
3. In Eclipse I select **Import > Existing Maven Projects**  then I choose my plugin.

At this point I receive the following errors ...

- No marketplace entries found to handle maven-jira-plugin:4.2.20:compress-resources in Eclipse.  Please see Help for more information.
- No marketplace entries found to handle maven-jira-plugin:4.2.20:copy-bundled-dependencies in Eclipse
- No marketplace entries found to handle maven-jira-plugin:4.2.20:copy-test-bundled-dependencies in Eclipse
- No marketplace entries found to handle maven-jira-plugin:4.2.20:filter-plugin-descriptor in Eclipse
- No marketplace entries found to handle maven-jira-plugin:4.2.20:filter-test-plugin-descriptor in Eclipse
- No marketplace entries found to handle maven-jira-plugin:4.2.20:generate-manifest in Eclipse
- No marketplace entries found to handle maven-jira-plugin:4.2.20:generate-rest-docs in Eclipse
- No marketplace entries found to handle maven-jira-plugin:4.2.20:generate-test-manifest in Eclipse

I have tried to disable the Maven Nature, then run **atlas-mvn eclipse:clean** then convert back to a Maven project, but the errors come back when doing so. Any suggestions on how to fix this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to update eclipse configuration for Maven (new version is Atlassian SDK 5.0.0):
[https://developer.atlassian.com/display/DOCS/Set+Up+the+Eclipse+IDE+for+Windows#SetUptheEclipseIDEforWindows-Step4:InstalltheMavenEclipsePlugin](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/DOCS/Set+Up+the+Eclipse+IDE+for+Windows#SetUptheEclipseIDEforWindows-Step4%3aInstalltheMavenEclipsePlugin)

Comment: I just double checked and followed those steps once again, yet nothing changed.

Comment: If you updated Atlassian SDK after creating plugin you can try to update pom.xml:
<amps.version>5.0.0</amps.version>

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Atlassian SDK, you should use their maven wrapper which come together with the SDK installation.

You are seeing that problem in your Eclipse is because your local maven (which is used by your Eclipse, or maybe embedded maven) settings doesn't contain Atlassian info.

Do refer to [this](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/framework/atlassian-sdk/working-with-maven/) for how to add in the Atlassian repo into your `settings.xml`.

[image]

Or you can run the `atlas-mvn install` to download Atlassian library into your local repository.

Or for quick work-around, you can just point your Maven to the Atlassian `settings.xml` as below:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I switched from using Eclipse to IntelliJ. IntelliJ makes importing Maven projects incredibly simple. If anyone else encounters this problem, I suggest switching to IntelliJ.